# write all console output to a file at end of script

Tags: powershell

i have a long script that checks at different parts of the script for things like connection, csv file created, data updated, etc...

so essentially looks like this:

```
write-host "connection successful!"
#50 lines later of some code doing stuff ...
write-host "csv file created!"
#more code here doing stuff
write-host "data updated!"
```

now instead of redirecting output at every single write-host/console output to a file, is there a way i can simply copy console output to a file at once at the end of the script?

pseudocode of what i want:

```
direct ALL console outputs to file ./log.txt
```

Comment: I believe the cmdlet `Start-Transcript` would help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript

Comment: @Persistent13 interesting, do i place that at beginning of script or at the end?

Comment: @Persistent13 ok i just tried it at beginning of file, its great, but the problem is its outputting more information that i didnt write myself, like user, hostname, etc...i dont want this information, how can i suppress this header input and footer information?

Comment: if `Start-Transcript` gives you more than you want, you can use one of at least 3 methods -- [1] add the `Tee-Object` cmdlet to the end of your `Write-Host` lines & save the result to a $Var [2] store the message in a $Var before sending it to the console & then accumulate that $Var into a $Collection [3] write a wrapper function like `Write-LogInfo` that handles both sending to the console and sending output to any other target.

Comment: `Write-Host` is not written to any stream. You cannot redirect a `Write-Host` message or assign it to a variable, or to a pipe.